# Rails (5.2.2) AJAX call for partial not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, partial-views

Short and sweet, I have followed [this guide](https://blog.codeship.com/unobtrusive-javascript-via-ajax-rails/#disqus_thread) *exactly* on a fresh rails deployment (5.2.2), using `rails g scaffold thing` to generate the app.

However,  after making the partial `_show.html.erb` under the paragraph **Targeted Changes** in the guide, clicking the "Change below" `link_to` does not render the partial when testing. I get no error message, and Rails tells me that everything is rendered OK, but nothing happens on the site when I click the link.

What am I missing?

---

**Code**:

`controllers/things_controller`

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @things = Thing.all
  end

  def show
  end

end
```

`config/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'things#index'
  resources :things
end
```

`things/index.html.erb`

```
<%# /app/views/things/index.html.erb %>
<%= link_to 'Change Below', thing_path(42), remote: true %>

<div id="target-for-change">
  Now you see "ME"!
</div>
```

`things/show.js.erb`

```
<%# /app/views/things/show.js.erb %>
$("#target-for-change").html("<%= j render(partial: 'show') %>");
```

`things/_show.html.erb`

```
<%# /app/views/things/_show.html.erb %>
Now you don't!
```

---

**Browser Console output**:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1
    at processResponse (rails-ujs.self-d109d8c5c0194c8ad60b8838b2661c5596b5c955987f7cd4045eb2fb90ca5343.js?body=1:268)
    at rails-ujs.self-d109d8c5c0194c8ad60b8838b2661c5596b5c955987f7cd4045eb2fb90ca5343.js?body=1:196
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (rails-ujs.self-d109d8c5c0194c8ad60b8838b2661c5596b5c955987f7cd4045eb2fb90ca5343.js?body=1:251)
```

Comment: What's the response browser console?

Comment: are you using `turbolinks`? If yes then try after removing `turbolinks`

Comment: @TalhaJunaid, I've added the Browser Console output.

Comment: @G.B, removing turbolinks does not solve it, same behaviour.

Comment: @tmo I have added the answer, please view this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on your console output, '$' is not defined. '$' is the common alias for jQuery so when you do:

```
$("#target-for-change").html("<%= j render(partial: 'show') %>");
```

you are telling jQuery to find a certain identifier. The thing is that you did not include the library in your project. A way to do it is by adding this line in your gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

and then this in your assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery3
```

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, and welcome so SO. I just read that jquery was discontinued in 5.1, so that must be it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the jquery in your project. Add this line to `application.html.erb`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or you can use the gem [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails)